# C# CoreAudio API problem with null session names

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to build a windows application in C# to control and manage the Windows Volume Mixer by using the Core Audio api. The issue I'm facing is regarding getting Session names, I'm able to do so by fetching the Session assigned Process ID but the following code produces null lines.

```
using System;
using CoreAudio;

namespace app
{
    public static class Start
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            MMDevice device;

            MMDeviceEnumerator DevEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator();

            device = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia);

            int num = device.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(device.AudioSessionManager2.Sessions[i].DisplayName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result when executing the code:

```
Mozilla Firefox

Mozilla Firefox
Mozilla Firefox
Mozilla Firefox
Mozilla Firefox

Mozilla Firefox
Mozilla Firefox
Mozilla Firefox
@%SystemRoot\System32\AudioSrv.DLL,-202

Mozilla Firefox

Mozilla Firefox
```

This causes the following problem: since sessions are detected as null, they don't trigger the notifications relative to a newly added session.

Comment: Accoring to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol-getdisplayname#remarks): *If the client has not called `IAudioSessionControl::SetDisplayName` to set the display name, the string will be empty.*

Comment: So it is not something I can fix in my code? Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: For the same test video, when it is opened in Firefox and Chrome, chrome does not display the session name, and [`IAudioSessionControl::GetDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol-getdisplayname) returns `S_OK`.